# How move file into a new directory instead of deleting them

Tags: python, shutil

I was able to figure how to find and delete empty folders in a directory and it works. Here is my code

```
import os
import shutil
import colorama

from os.path import join, isfile

def walksub(dir):
    isEmpty=True
    subDirs=[]

    for entry in os.listdir(dir):
        try:
            if isfile(join(dir,entry))==True:
               isEmpty = False
            else:
                subEmpty =  walksub(join(dir, entry))
                if subEmpty==True:
                   subDirs.append(join(dir, entry))
                else:
                    isEmpty=False
        except :
            print ("error checking: "+entry)
            isEmpty=False
    if isEmpty == False:
       for subDir in subDirs:
           currentnumber = subDirs.index(subDir)
           print (subDir)

           os.rmdir(subDir) # delete the empty folders


     return isEmpty

walksub("DBpics")
```

Instead of deleting the empty folders with os.rmdir(subDir). I want to move them to a new directory. How can I implement this ?

i defined destination folders as

```
    emptyfolders ="/Emptyfolders/"
```

and then attempt to move files instead of deleting

```
  shutil.move(subDir,emptyfolders)
```

the error message is

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Emptyfolders/'

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shutil.html#shutil.move

Comment: Am unrelated, but important beginner lesson: Never compare a Boolean value to `True` or `False`. This is an antipattern. The Boolean value is `True` or `False` *itself*, it does not need to be compared to anything to "become" `True` or `False`. `if isfile(join(dir,entry))==True:` is much better written as `if isfile(join(dir,entry)):`. The `if isEmpty == False:` becomes `if not isEmpty:`. This is not only shorter, it's also much more natural to read. This also applies to the other occurrences of this in your code.

Comment: @learner101, the permission denied error you're getting is pretty clear: your current user doesn't have the permission to actually move the `/Emptyfolders` directory.  The problem isn't in the function you're calling, but rather the user you are calling with.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a way to move the directory, you're already importing `shutil`.  It has a move function which applies to directories as well:

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shutil.html#shutil.move

Comment: bring an example will make this answer the correct one.

Comment: I tried but I could not get it work with src and destination declaration

Comment: @learner101, could you, then, show us the code which uses `shutil.move` and the error you're getting?

Comment: @Arman, not to be argumentative, but the link is to the Python documentation, which explicitly states, "Recursively move a file or directory (src) to another location (dst) and return the destination."  I'm curious why I would need more information than this?

Comment: @Arman, just to clarify: I haven't posted on SO for a while, and so am curious if the requirements for answers have changed :)

Comment: no it did not change , I just tried to make you a point for improve your answer :)